# Facebook app not setup

Tags: facebook, authentication, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error:

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

This being said and as explained online I did made the app available, and added a contact email.

not sure if it plays but I am using firebase and also followed the instructions on there.

Comment: You have taken the app live? And you still get that error?

Comment: yea do you have any idea what it could be?

Comment: If you are 100% sure that you taken the app live then file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs